# 10% sugar in berries -- what's the rest?

Tags: nutrition-information

According to packages on frozen berries (e.g. raspberry, blueberry and others), 10g out of 100g consists of sugar, 1g of other carbohydrates, and 0-1g of protein. What about the rest? Is it just water?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say water and fiber. Look at a dried blueberry vs. a fresh one... there's practically nothing left after you dry it.

Comment: Isn't fiber included in "other carbohydrates" on the nutrition label?

Comment: Yes, fiber should be part of the "other carbohydrates" if it isn't mentioned specifically on the label.